# Can I Display Different Data Depending On What Row Number Is In Return, MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, return, rows

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id='$pageid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 

    $id = $row["id"];
    $titleCurVid = $row["title"];
    $keywords = $row["keywords"];

    $returnVariable = 'Hi, I am the first return in the MYSQL select';
    }
```

I want the $returnVariable to display different thing depending on what # return. 
for example. 
I want for the,

```
$returnVariable = 'Hi, I am the SECOND return in MYSQL';
```

to display that in the second returned row. I am sorry for my horrible explenation, I am just new to php and I don't know the terminology very well.

Comment: I actually Meant to remove the WHERE id='$pageid' and replace it with WHERE featured='y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, problem solved. I just did 4 different of these fetches.

- 1st Return (the one with the unique, special format display):

  ```
  $sql_storyPublisher1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM story ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_storyPublisher1))
  {
      $publisherID1 = $row["id"];
      $publishertitle1 = $row["title"];
      $returnVariable1 = '<li id="selected" class="firstSlide YellowSelected">' . $publisherID1 . '</li>';    
  }
  ```

Thanks for the help everyone, I guess the simple solution what just using the OFFSET command.

- 2nd, 3rd & 4th Return (obviously replacing the number 2 with whatever # return it is):

  ```
  $sql_storyPublisher2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM story ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_storyPublisher2))
  {
      $publisherID2 = $row["id"];
      $publishertitle2 = $row["title"];
      $returnVariable2 = '<li id="" class="secondSlide">' . $publisherID2 . '</li>';  
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that stores the numbers (something like `$arr = array(1 => "first", 2 => "second", 3 => "third", 4 => "fourth");` and so on
Then use a counter variable to access that array within the loop.
Here's what I'm thinking...

```
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id='$pageid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";  
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());  

    $arr = array(1 => "first", 2 => "second", 3 => "third", 4 => "fourth", 5 => "fifth"); //and so on
    $counter = 1
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {  

        $id = $row["id"]; 
        $titleCurVid = $row["title"]; 
        $keywords = $row["keywords"]; 

        $returnVariable = 'Hi, I am the '.$arr[$counter].' return in the MYSQL select'; 
$counter++;
        }
```

The syntax may be incorrect, but you get the idea. Note that the above example only shows it if there are 5 or less records.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I get what your saying but I need to be able to create different varriable names depending on what array return # it is, and uniquely formatted data, with different html tags

$returnVariable1 ='<div>hi i am number one<div>' (first return) -------------------          
$returnVariable2 ='<span>hi i am number 2</span>' (2nd return)---------------------
$returnVariable3 ='<td>hi i am number 3</td>' (3rd return)-------------------------
$returnVariable4 ='<tr>hi i am number 4</tr>' (4th return)-------------------

Comment: Ah, you want to create $returnVariable1, $returnVariable2... on the fly? You can try using PHP variable variables, where you'd use 2 dollar-signs to dynamically create the variables, something like "$returnVariable=$$returnVariable.$counter". Read about it here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @Alex, if the results are limited to 4 anyway, then you could even do without the while loop and just call mysqli_fetch_array 4 times.

Comment: so you're saying do four separate mysqli_fetch_array, and OFFSET each one but one more than the last, so that ill get four different (where i can create completely differently formatted data in each) variables to echo out in my body? And btw, why i need four different formatted variables is because i am fetching FEATURED stories from my cms and displaying them in a Jquery controlled, featured, news slider. The first <li> contains different div ids and classes, but i still want to dynamicly echo out data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make four separate queries to the database... I meant something more like this:

```
///// 1st Return (the one with the unique, special format display) =

$sql_storyPublisher1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM story ORDER BY id DESC");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_storyPublisher1);

$publisherID1 = $row["id"];
$publishertitle1 = $row["title"];

$returnVariable1 = '<li id="selected" class="firstSlide YellowSelected">' . $publisherID1 . '</li>';    

///// 2nd, 3rd & 4th Return (obviously replacing the number 2 with whatever # return it is) =

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_storyPublisher2);

$publisherID2 = $row["id"];
$publishertitle2 = $row["title"];

$returnVariable2 = '<li id="" class="secondSlide">' . $publisherID2 . '</li>';
```

Of course there are probably better ways to do it, but this is simple and readable. You might want to make sure you'll actually have 4 rows. you can us `if` if you're not sure:

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_storyPublisher2)) {

    $publisherID2 = $row["id"];
    $publishertitle2 = $row["title"];

    $returnVariable2 = '<li id="" class="secondSlide">' . $publisherID2 . '</li>';  
}
```